# Multithreaded matrix multiplication in C

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix, pthreads

I'm trying to do some multithreaded high performance c matrix multiplication, the code below here is the program i wrote in C, it just works fine when the # of cores is 12 (since my pc has 12 threads or when i manually fix it to 12) when I switch it to a lower value (like 10 f.e.) gives me strange results, doesn anyone have an idea on what the problem could be?

Tested an perfectly working with 12 cores (or threads, call as whatever u want ) with a lower number of cores doesn't work anymore (look like he ends the execution almost immediately)
Tried with different values but looks like there is an error in the code I can't figure out probably.
The error is present in big size matrices but sometimes also in small size matrices

```c
//
// Created by christian on 06/09/2019.
//

#pragma GCC optimize("O3", "unroll-loops", "omit-frame-pointer", "inline") //Optimization flags
#pragma GCC option("arch=native", "tune=native", "no-zero-upper") //Enable AVX
#pragma GCC target("avx")  //Enable AVX

#include <time.h>    // for clock_t, clock(), CLOCKS_PER_SEC
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h> //AVX/SSE Extensions are included in stdio.h
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int ops = 0;

//define matrix size (in this case we'll use a square matrix)
#define DIM 200 //DO NOT EXCEED 10000 (modification to the stack size needed)

float matrix[DIM][DIM];
float result_matrix[DIM][DIM];

float *matrix_ptr = (float *) &matrix;
float *result_ptr = (float *) &result_matrix;

// set the number of logical cores to 1 (just in case the auto-detection doesn't work properly)
int cores = 1;

//functions prototypes
void single_multiply(int row);

void *thread_multiply(void *offset);

int detect_number_of_cores();

void fill_matrix();

int main() {

    //two instructions needed for pseudo-random float numbers
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

    //detect the number of active cores
    cores = detect_number_of_cores();

    //matrix filling with random float values
    fill_matrix();

    printf("------------- MATRIX MULTIPLICATION -------------\n");
    printf("--- multi-thread (vectorization enabled) v1.0 ---\n");

//    printf("\n ORIGINAL MATRIX");
//    for(int c=0; c<DIM; c++){
//        printf("\n");
//        for(int k=0; k<DIM; k++){
//            printf("%f \t", matrix[c][k]);
//        }
//    }

    //uncomment and modify this value to force a particular number of threads (not recommended)
    //cores = 4;

    printf("\n Currently using %i cores", cores);

    printf("\n Matrix size:  %i x %i", DIM, DIM);

    //time detection struct declaration
    struct timeval start, end;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    //decisional tree for the number of threads to be used
    if (cores == 0 || cores == 1 || cores > DIM) {
        //passing 0 because it has to start from the first row
        single_multiply(0);


        //this value may not be correct if matrix size exceeds 80x80 due to thread lock problems
        printf("\n Total multiply ops: %i", ops);

        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

        long seconds = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
        long micros = ((seconds * 1000000) + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_usec);

        printf("\n\n Time elapsed is %d seconds and %d micros\n", seconds, micros);
        return 0;

    } else {

        //split the matrix in more parts (as much as the number of active cores)
        int rows_por_thread = DIM / cores;
        printf("\n Rows por Thread: %i", rows_por_thread);
        //calculate the rest of the division (if there is one obviously)
        int rest = DIM % cores;
        printf("\n Rest: %i \n", rest);

        if (rest == 0) {
            //execute just the multi-thread function n times
            int times = rows_por_thread;

            //create an array of thread-like objects
            pthread_t threads[cores];
            //create an array with the arguments for each thread
            int thread_args[cores];

            //launching the threads according to the available cores
            int i = 0;
            int error;
            for (int c = 0; c < DIM; c += rows_por_thread) {
                thread_args[i] = c;
                i++;
            }
            for (int c = 0; c < cores; c++) {
                error = pthread_create(&threads[c], NULL, thread_multiply, (void *) &thread_args[c]);
                if (error != 0) {
                    printf("\n Error in thread %i creation, exiting...", c);
                }
                printf("created thread n %i with argument: %i \n", c, thread_args[c]);
            }
            printf("\n ... working ...");
            for (int c = 0; c < cores; c++) {
                pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
                printf("\n Waiting to join thread n: %i", c);
            }


        } else {

            //THE PROBLEM MUST BE INSIDE THIS ELSE STATEMENT

            //execute the multi-thread function n times and the single function th rest remaining times
            printf("\n The number of cores is NOT a divisor of the size of the matrix. \n");

            //create an array of thread-like objects
            pthread_t threads[cores];
            //create an array with the arguments for each thread
            int thread_args[cores];

            //launching the threads according to the available cores
            int i = 0;  //counter for the thread ID
            int entrypoint_residual_rows = 0;   //first unprocessed residual row

            //launching the threads according to the available coreS
            for (int c = 0; c < DIM; c += rows_por_thread) {
                thread_args[i] = c;
                i++;
            }

            entrypoint_residual_rows = cores * rows_por_thread;
            int error;
            //launch the threads
            for (int c = 0; c < cores; c++) {
                error = pthread_create(&threads[c], NULL, thread_multiply, (void *) &thread_args[c]);
                if (error != 0) {
                    printf("\n Error in thread %i creation, exiting...", c);
                }
                printf("created thread n %i with argument: %i \n", c, thread_args[c]);
            }
            printf("\n ... working ...\n");
            //join all the previous generated threads
            for (int c = 0; c < cores; c++) {
                pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
                printf("\n Waiting to join thread n: %i", c);
            }
            printf("\n entry-point index for the single function %i ", entrypoint_residual_rows);
            single_multiply(entrypoint_residual_rows);
        }
    }

//    printf("\n MULTIPLIED MATRIX");
//    for (int c = 0; c < DIM; c++) {
//        printf("\n");
//        for (int k = 0; k < DIM; k++) {
//            printf("%f \t", result_matrix[c][k]);
//        }
//    }

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    printf("\n All threads joined correctly");

    long seconds = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
    long micros = ((seconds * 1000000) + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_usec);

    printf("\n\n Time elapsed is %d seconds and %d micros\n", seconds, micros);

    //this value may not be correct if matrix size exceeds 80x80 due to thread lock problems
    printf("\n Total multiply ops: %i", ops);

    return 0;
}

//detect number of cores of the CPU (logical cores)
int detect_number_of_cores() {
    return (int) sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN); // Get the number of logical CPUs.
}

//matrix filling function
void fill_matrix() {
    float a = 5.0;
    for (int c = 0; c < DIM; c++)
        for (int d = 0; d < DIM; d++) {
            matrix[c][d] = (float) rand() / (float) (RAND_MAX) * a;
        }
}

//row by row multiplication algorithm (mono-thread version)
void single_multiply(int row) {
    for (int i = row; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            *(result_ptr + i * DIM + j) = 0;
            ops++;
            for (int k = 0; k < DIM; k++) {
                *(result_ptr + i * DIM + j) += *(matrix_ptr + i * DIM + k) * *(matrix_ptr + k * DIM + j);
            }
        }
    }
}

//thread for the multiplication algorithm
void *thread_multiply(void *offset) {
    //de-reference the parameter passed by the main-thread
    int *row_offset = (int *) offset;
    //multiplication loops
    for (int i = *row_offset; i < (*row_offset + (DIM / cores)); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            *(result_ptr + i * DIM + j) = 0;

            ops++;

            for (int k = 0; k < DIM; k++) {
                *(result_ptr + i * DIM + j) += *(matrix_ptr + i * DIM + k) * *(matrix_ptr + k * DIM + j);
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

this is the way the result looks (also the number of ops in the result should be equal to size x size)

```c
------------- MATRIX MULTIPLICATION -------------
--- multi-thread (vectorization enabled) v1.0 ---

 Currently using 4 cores
 Matrix size:  200 x 200
 Rows por Thread: 50
 Rest: 0 
created thread n 0 with argument: 0 
created thread n 1 with argument: 50 
created thread n 2 with argument: 100 
created thread n 3 with argument: 150 

 ... working ...
 Waiting to join thread n: 0
 Waiting to join thread n: 1
 Waiting to join thread n: 2
 Waiting to join thread n: 3
 All threads joined correctly

 Time elapsed is 0 seconds and 804 micros

 Total multiply ops: 2200
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: When you call `srand((unsigned int) time(NULL)` you get a different seed on each run, so that the runs cannot be repeated - this is unhelpful for unit testing. Use the same seed and compare the result of your computations with the expected result.

Comment: Specify what is the expected result and what you actually get. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, Maxim, I knew about that, for testing purposes i used the same seed obviusly but the problem isn't abou that, if you tried running the program you will be able to see that changing the # of cores or the matrix size, stranger things happen to the output. I hope this could give u a better understanding of the problem. sorry I'm a bit newbie with multithreading in c.

Comment: The expected result will be a normal execution that would produce deterministic results (sometimes it looks like as if it return immediately doing nothing even for big matrices). Especially when the number of cores (and consecutively the number of maximum threads is lower than 12 which is the number of logical cores of my PC) I get strange results. It looks like it's not executing all the calcs needed. I hope u understand what I'm trying to say

Comment: I think you are overfilling the `thread_args[]` array in the `else` branch. I think `for (int c = 0; c < DIM; c += rows_por_thread)` should be `for (int c = 0; c < DIM - rest; c += rows_por_thread)`.

Answer (score 0):

This `pthread_join` here looks extremely fishy -- observe how the loop variable is `c`, but you index the array on `i`:

```
for (int c = 0; c < cores; c++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    printf("\n Waiting to join thread n: %i", c);
}
```

I doubt it's doing the right thing.

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the problems, I solved it putting the correct index of the thread to be joined. By the way I still have the same main problem: non deterministic results. I expect the number of total ops (the number of cells written in the result matrix) to be as much as the product of DIMxDIM but at each run i get a different number. I tried locking the threads to avoid concurrency problems accessing the ops variable but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

in thread_multiple, the unadorned line:

```
ops++;
```

looks a bit suspicious.  Did you not say you were running multiple instances of these threads?
As a general comment, you should look to have your functions a bit better defined; for example if you changed your single_multiply to be:

```
int single_multiply(int RowStart, int RowEnd) {
     int ops = 0;
 ....
     return ops;
}
```

then

```
void *thread_multiply(void *p) {
      int  *rows = p;
      int  ops;
      ops = single_multiply(rows[0], rows[1]);
      return (void *)ops;
}
```

you have:

- reduced the bit of code that cares about things like 'cores' to the only bit that matters about them.
- removed contention on the counter (you can collect them in pthread_join)
- removed the redundant, nearly identical code.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, basically the single multiply function will handle just the rows of the matrix that can't be handler with the multithread function (the remainder of the division of matrix / number of threads basically. Anyway i modified the single_multiply function so that now it's more clear what it does effectively do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You ALL guys, this is now what it looks like, i would have expected better performance honeslty but at least it looks like it's working, does anyone have some idea on performance improvements I could do?

```c
//
// Created by christian on 06/09/2019.
//

#pragma GCC optimize("O3", "unroll-loops", "omit-frame-pointer", "inline") //Optimization flags
#pragma GCC option("arch=native", "tune=native", "no-zero-upper") //Enable AVX
#pragma GCC target("avx")  //Enable AVX

#include <time.h>    // for clock_t, clock(), CLOCKS_PER_SEC
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h> //AVX/SSE Extensions are included in stdio.h
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


//define matrix size (in this case we'll use a square matrix)
#define DIM 4000 //DO NOT EXCEED 10000 (modification to the stack size needed)

float matrix[DIM][DIM];
float result_matrix[DIM][DIM];

float *matrix_ptr = (float *) &matrix;
float *result_ptr = (float *) &result_matrix;

// set the number of logical cores to 1 (just in case the auto-detection doesn't work properly)
int cores = 1;

//functions prototypes
void single_multiply(int rowStart, int rowEnd);

void *thread_multiply(void *offset);

int detect_number_of_cores();

void fill_matrix();

int main() {

    //two instructions needed for pseudo-random float numbers
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

    //detect the number of active cores
    cores = detect_number_of_cores();

    //matrix filling with random float values
    fill_matrix();

    printf("------------- MATRIX MULTIPLICATION -------------\n");
    printf("--- multi-thread (vectorization enabled) v1.0 ---\n");

//    printf("\n ORIGINAL MATRIX");
//    for(int c=0; c<DIM; c++){
//        printf("\n");
//        for(int k=0; k<DIM; k++){
//            printf("%f \t", matrix[c][k]);
//        }
//    }

    //uncomment and modify this value to force a particular number of threads (not recommended)
    //cores = 4;

    printf("\n Currently using %i cores", cores);

    printf("\n Matrix size:  %i x %i", DIM, DIM);

    //time detection struct declaration
    struct timeval start, end;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    //decisional tree for the number of threads to be used
    if (cores == 0 || cores == 1 || cores > DIM) {
        //passing 0 because it has to start from the first row
        single_multiply(0, DIM);

        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

        long seconds = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
        long micros = ((seconds * 1000000) + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_usec);

        printf("\n\n Time elapsed is %ld seconds and %ld micros\n", seconds, micros);
        return 0;

    } else {

        //split the matrix in more parts (as much as the number of active cores)
        int rows_por_thread = DIM / cores;
        printf("\n Rows por Thread: %i", rows_por_thread);
        //calculate the rest of the division (if there is one obviously)
        int rest = DIM % cores;
        printf("\n Rest: %i \n", rest);

        if (rest == 0) {
            //execute just the multi-thread function n times
            int times = rows_por_thread;

            //create an array of thread-like objects
            pthread_t threads[cores];
            //create an array with the arguments for each thread
            int thread_args[cores];

            //launching the threads according to the available cores
            int i = 0;
            int error;
            for (int c = 0; c < DIM; c += rows_por_thread) {
                thread_args[i] = c;
                i++;
            }
            for (int c = 0; c < cores; c++) {
                error = pthread_create(&threads[c], NULL, thread_multiply, (void *) &thread_args[c]);
                if (error != 0) {
                    printf("\n Error in thread %i creation", c);
                }
                printf("created thread n %i with argument: %i \n", c, thread_args[c]);
            }
            printf("\n ... working ...");
            for (int c = 0; c < cores; c++) {
                error = pthread_join(threads[c], NULL);
                if (error != 0) {
                    printf("\n Error in thread %i join", c);
                }
                printf("\n Waiting to join thread n: %i", c);
            }

        } else {

            //THE PROBLEM MUST BE INSIDE THIS ELSE STATEMENT

            //execute the multi-thread function n times and the single function th rest remaining times
            printf("\n The number of cores is NOT a divisor of the size of the matrix. \n");

            //create an array of thread-like objects
            pthread_t threads[cores];
            //create an array with the arguments for each thread
            int thread_args[cores];

            //launching the threads according to the available cores
            int i = 0;  //counter for the thread ID
            int entrypoint_residual_rows = 0;   //first unprocessed residual row

            //launching the threads according to the available coreS
            for (int c = 0; c < DIM - rest; c += rows_por_thread) {
                thread_args[i] = c;
                i++;
            }

            entrypoint_residual_rows = cores * rows_por_thread;
            int error;
            //launch the threads
            for (int c = 0; c < cores; c++) {
                error = pthread_create(&threads[c], NULL, thread_multiply, (void *) &thread_args[c]);
                if (error != 0) {
                    printf("\n Error in thread %i creation, exiting...", c);
                }
                printf("created thread n %i with argument: %i \n", c, thread_args[c]);
            }

            printf("\n ... working ...\n");
            //join all the previous generated threads
            for (int c = 0; c < cores; c++) {
                pthread_join(threads[c], NULL);
                printf("\n Waiting to join thread n: %i", c);
            }
            printf("\n entry-point index for the single function %i ", entrypoint_residual_rows);
            single_multiply(entrypoint_residual_rows, DIM);
        }
    }

//    printf("\n MULTIPLIED MATRIX");
//    for (int c = 0; c < DIM; c++) {
//        printf("\n");
//        for (int k = 0; k < DIM; k++) {
//            printf("%f \t", result_matrix[c][k]);
//        }
//    }

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    printf("\n All threads joined correctly");

    long seconds = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
    long micros = ((seconds * 1000000) + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_usec);

    printf("\n\n Time elapsed is %d seconds and %d micros\n", seconds, micros);


    return 0;
}

//detect number of cores of the CPU (logical cores)
int detect_number_of_cores() {
    return (int) sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN); // Get the number of logical CPUs.
}

//matrix filling function
void fill_matrix() {
    float a = 5.0;
    for (int c = 0; c < DIM; c++)
        for (int d = 0; d < DIM; d++) {
            matrix[c][d] = (float) rand() / (float) (RAND_MAX) * a;
        }
}

//row by row multiplication algorithm (mono-thread version)
void single_multiply(int rowStart, int rowEnd) {
    for (int i = rowStart; i < rowEnd; i++) {
        //printf("\n %i", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            *(result_ptr + i * DIM + j) = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < DIM; k++) {
                *(result_ptr + i * DIM + j) += *(matrix_ptr + i * DIM + k) * *(matrix_ptr + k * DIM + j);
            }
        }
    }
}

//thread for the multiplication algorithm
void *thread_multiply(void *offset) {
    //de-reference the parameter passed by the main-thread
    int *row_offset = (int *) offset;
    printf(" Starting at line %i ending at line %i \n ", *row_offset, *row_offset + (DIM / cores));
    single_multiply(*row_offset, *row_offset + (DIM / cores));
    printf("\n ended at line %i", *row_offset + (DIM / cores));
    return NULL;
}
```